# Simple Address Book using dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, dynamic, allocation

I am working on my school project related to "keeping contacts of customers" in C++.
I already finished my project using std::vector to store contact information for every added person. But now i have to write the same thing using DYNAMIC ARRAY.

Does anybody have any idea or sample code how to declare dynamic array with ability to change its dimension according to how many contacts are added by user ?

I need following:
 * Declaration of dynamic array with undefined number of persons and with 6 contacts per each.
 * Add a new contact.
 * List all contacts in array.

I finished my project using vectors without any problems, but right now i am lost. I studied a lot of articles about working with dynamic arrays in c++ but with no progress. I was searching all around the internet for a sample piece of code that does what i need but can't find anything.

Comment: std::vector IS a dynamic array.

Comment: @Till I think he refers to old C style pointer malloc-ed array.

Comment: @texasbruce ow, now I see and totally understand the didactic value - though if I was the teacher, I would have done it the other way around...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this is not exactly the same as your project, this was mine from a few days ago and we had to use a 2d dynamic array using the "new" and "delete" method for strings of names.  Remember that any time you use "new" you need to have a "delete" otherwise you will get memory leaks. I hope this helps.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#include <memory.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include "ReadString.h"
#include "sort.h"


void main ()
{
bool contMain=true;
const long numNames=20;
long nameAc=0;
char ** ppNames;
ppNames=new char* [numNames];
char test;

while(contMain && nameAc<numNames)
{
    ppNames[nameAc]=ReadString();
    test=ppNames[nameAc][0];
    if(test=='\0')
    {
        contMain=false;
    }
    nameAc++;   
}
cout<<"Your names unsorted are:"<<endl;
print(ppNames, nameAc);
ppNames=sort(ppNames, nameAc);
cout<<"Your names, sorted, are:"<<endl;
print(ppNames, nameAc);


// deallocation... this will delete pNames and pTemp from the ReadString function
// as well as ppNames in main because they are all using the same pointers.
for(int i=0; i<nameAc; i++)
{
    delete ppNames [i];
}
delete[] ppNames;
}
```

And here is the ReadString function.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <memory.h>
#include "ReadString.h"

using namespace std;


char * ReadString()
{
long aSize=10;
long numChars (0);
char * pNames;
char * pTemp;
char c;
pNames=new char [aSize+1];

while((c = cin.get()) != '\n')
{
    if(numChars >= aSize)
    {
        aSize += numChars;
        pTemp = new char[aSize + 1];
        memcpy(pTemp, pNames, numChars);
        delete[] pNames;
        pNames = pTemp;
        cout << "Array size increased to " << aSize << endl;
    }
    pNames[numChars++] = c;
}
pNames[numChars] = '\0'; //end of string
return pNames;
```

Answer (score 0):

one thing you can easily use for this are linked lists. Your data structure has a pointer to the next list element.

```
struct ListElement 
{
    CustomerData cutomer;
    ListElement *next;
}
```

You can add infrastructure for adding removing, finding, print-all etc. using such a datastructure as basis.

**Another way** is doing it really dynamic:

Example adding one item:

1. malloc memory for as many items as you already have + 1
2. copy the data from the old to the new memory
3. add the new item at the with +1 allocated space

You'll need infrastructure for adding at the beginning, at the end, delete one in the middle etc. going with this scheme. Allocate as much memory as you need after the change, copy the old data, insert/remove one item.

Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

The best that I can so is to suggest links to articles.  It sounds like your instructor wants you to write the same program in "the hard way" using a more primitive set of tools.  Since std::vector is essentially a dynamic array, I have to assume that he wants you to rewrite the project where you have to manually manage the memory.  Here are some starting points.  Remember, that google is your friend!

[C++ FAQ Lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/intrinsics-delete-array.html)

[Dynamic Memory Cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/)

[LMGTFY](http://bit.ly/1bNOI8i)